# document.querySelector Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (92:9)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to figure out why babel logs: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (92:9). For the sake of brevity I'm only adding the beginning and ending of the component.

```
class PlaylistSearchBar extends Component{

constructor(){

    this.state = {
        term: {
            tracks: [],
            playlists: [] 
        }
    };
}

error here --> document.querySelector(".search").addEventListener('click', function() {
         input = document.querySelector("input").value;
         this.searchForQueries(input);
    });

and here --> document.querySelector(".input-search").addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

        var input = document.querySelector(".input-search").value;

        if (e.which === 13) {
                this.searchForQueries(input);
        }
    });

render(){
        return(
            <div class="main">
                    <div class="ui massive icon input">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search for a song or artist..." class="js-search input-search"/>
                        <i class="search icon js-submit"></i>
                    </div>
                    <button onclick="localStorageClear();" class="clear">Clear Playlist</button>
            </div>

            <div class="search-results js-search-results ui cards">

            </div>
        );
        <Playlist playlists = {this.state.term.playlists} setTracksToNil = {this.setState({tracks: []});} embedItems = {this.getEmbed}/>
    }
}
```

Comment: Format your code and check your curly braces.  they don't seem to include either of those statements....they are hanging in the wind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class PlaylistSearchBar extends Component{

constructor(){

    this.state = {
        term: {
            tracks: [],
            playlists: [] 
        }
    };
//REMOVED BRACKET HERE

error here -->  THESE SHOULD BE IN RENDER


and here --> 
render(){
document.querySelector(".search").addEventListener('click', function() {
         input = document.querySelector("input").value;
         this.searchForQueries(input);
    });
    document.querySelector(".input-search").addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

        var input = document.querySelector(".input-search").value;

        if (e.which === 13) {
                this.searchForQueries(input);
        }
    });

        return(
            <div class="main">
                    <div class="ui massive icon input">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search for a song or artist..." class="js-search input-search"/>
                        <i class="search icon js-submit"></i>
                    </div>
                    <button onclick="localStorageClear();" class="clear">Clear Playlist</button>
            </div>

            <div class="search-results js-search-results ui cards">
               <Playlist playlists = {this.state.term.playlists} setTracksToNil = {this.setState({tracks: []});} embedItems = {this.getEmbed}/>
            </div>
        );
      //PLAYLIST SHOULDNT BE OUTSIDE OF RETURN
    }
}
```